# parse.com: Cloud code equivalent for REST API "where"?

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I want to query a class ***album*** inside a cloud code.

With the [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) API I do a http `GET` request with `where={"geo_plz":{"$gte":32000,"$lte":33000},"cost":{"$gte":10,"$lte":20}}`

How can I run the same query inside a cloud code?

Comment: Did you look at the JavaScript docs?

Comment: Sure, but my I want my "where"-parameter flexible.

Comment: I know i can do something like this:
`
var query1 = new Parse.Query(Event);
var query2 = new Parse.Query(Event);
query2.greaterThanOrEqualTo("geo_plz", "32000");
query2.lessThanOrEqualTo("geo_plz", "33000");
`

But what is if the "where"-parameter has additional params, like **"cost":{"$gte":10,"$lte":20}}**?

And the next query has **"count":{"$gte":1,"$lte":10}}** ?

I need this because I want only some fields of a class. If I do this on client side, the user could manipulate it, with cloud code it's more secure.

Comment: Here's my workaround for cloud code:

`var query = new Parse.Query("objekt");
    var where = (request.params.where) ? request.params.where : {};
    var limit = (request.params.limit) ? request.params.limit : 10;
    var skip = (request.params.skip) ? request.params.skip : 1;

    query._where = where; //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
    query.limit(limit);
    query.skip(skip);

    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            response.success(results);
        },
        error: function () {
            response.error("lookup failed");
        }

    });`